# Cannot read property 'top' of undefined. ScrollTop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make a Breadcrumb where you click in a  and it makes scroll animation to the target choosen, but I got next console error in each click `Cannot read property 'top' of undefined` 
Here is my jquery code:

```
$("ol#migas > li > span").click(function () {
        var targetName = $(this).attr("id");
        var targetOffset = $(targetName).offset().top;
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: targetOffset
            }, 1000)
})
```

And here the HTML:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb" id="migas">
    <h3>Índice</h3>
    <li class="nav-header">1 La historia del Wéstern:</li>
    <br>
    <li><span id="genero"><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1.1 Género</a></span></li>
    <br>
    <li class="nav-header">2 Historia:</li>
    <br>
    <li><span id="origen"><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 2.1 Origen</a></span></li>
    <br>
    <li><span id="oro"><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 2.2 Edad de oro</a></span></li>
    <br>
    <li><span id="decadencia"><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 2.3 Decadencia</a></span></li>
    <br>
    <li><span id="actualidad"><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 2.4 Actualidad</a></span></li>
    <br>
    <li class="nav-header">3 Subgéneros:</li>
    <br>
    <li><span id="spa"><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 3.1 Spaghetti wéstern</a></span></li>
    <br>
    <li><span id="crep"><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 3.2 Wéstern crepuscular</a></span></li>
    <br>
</ol>
```

Comment: Try debugging your code. It often helps.

Comment: Downvoter can you explain why this question deserve down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `id`  contains e.g. `actualidad` so `targetName` will contain `actualidad` and your:

```
var targetName = $(this).attr("id");
var targetOffset = $(targetName).offset().top;
```

Will result in:

```
$('actualidad').offset().top;
```

But there is not element with the **tag name** `actualidad` in your document, your have to write `$('#'+targetName).offset().top;` so search for the element with the ID `actualidad`.

To find such problems you should check the content of your jQuery result set:

```
var target = $(selector);
var targetOffset;

if( target.length > 0 ) {
   targetOffset = target.offset().top;
} else {
   console.error('Not element found for selector: '+selector);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.attr` only gives the `id` without the `#`. So you need to manually append `#` when using with jQuery selector like below

`var targetOffset = $("#"+targetName).offset().top;`